# Graph Theory: Systems of Distinct Representatives

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

In a collection {$S_1, S_2, ... S_n$} of $n\geq 2$ nonempty sets, no two sets have the same number of elements. Show that this collection has a system of distinct representatives

(a) by using Hall's theorem:
A collection {$S_1, S_2, ... S_n$} of $n$ nonempty finite sets has a system of distinct representatives if and only if, for each integer $k$ with $1\leq k\leq n$, the union of any $k$ of these sets contains at least $k$ elements.

(b) without using Hall's theorem.

It seems that I should begin by letting $|S_1|<|S_2|<\cdots<|S_n|$ and showing that, for any union of these sets, I will always get at least $k$ elements. It seems clear to me that the result is true, but I don't know how to prove this exactly.

Comment: Try using the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For (a), show that $|S_k|\ge k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$, and note that if $F\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then

$$\left|\bigcup_{k\in F}S_k\right|\ge|S_{\max F}|\;.$$

For (b), suppose not, and let $F\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$ be minimal such that $\{S_k:k\in F\}$ has no SDR. Let $m=\max F$. Let $T$ be an SDR for $\{S_k:k\in F\setminus\{m\}\}$. How must $S_m$ be related to $T$? Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 0):

(a) First, let us see a proof using Hall's theorem. We prove that a collection of sets $S_1$, $S_2$, $\ldots$, $S_n$ has a system of distinct representatives if and only if $$|\bigcup_{i\in I}S_{i}|\geq |I|,\space \forall \space I \in [n]$$ where $[n] = {1, 2, \ldots, n}.$ That is, for any collection of sets $S_i$'s, the number of elements must be at least as large as the number of sets.

Construct a bipartite graph $G = S \cup T$, where $S$ and $T$ are the two partite sets, defined as:
$$S = \{S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n\}$$
$$T = \{Elements \space of \space the \space set \space S_i\} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}S_{i}$$

An element (vertex) $S_i$ of $S$ is adjacent to $s_j$ $\in$ $T$ if and only if $s_{j} \in S_i$. Now consider the following series of arguments:

The collection of sets in $S$ has a system of distinct representatives

$\iff$ For every $S_i$ $(1 \leq i \leq n)$, there exists a distinct $s_i$ such that $s_i \in S_i$

$\iff$ $G$ admits a matching that saturates $S$

$\iff$ Hall's condition holds true, i.e. for any subset $A \subseteq S$, we have $|N(A)| \geq |A|$

(where $N(A) \subseteq T$ is the set of neighbors of $A$. In other words, $A = \{S_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $N(A) = \bigcup_{i\in I}S_{i}$)

$\iff$ $|\bigcup_{i\in I}S_{i}|\geq |I|$

$$$$
(b) Without  using Hall's theorem, [here's](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/book/section04.01.html) a nice and lengthy proof.